# How can I edit index HTML file after creating website s3 and apigateway via teraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-api-gateway

This tf code creates s3 that will host website. Index file has old API endpoint.
It creates s3 bucket, edits for static hosting, and uploads 4 s3 objects.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "frontend_vote" {
  bucket = "frontend-bucket-${var.vote}-${var.def_region}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "frontend_vote_s3_bucket_policy" {
  bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.id
  policy     = data.aws_iam_policy_document.frontend_vote_s3_bucket_policy.json
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote]

}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "frontend_vote_s3_bucket_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "PublicReadGetObject"

    principals {
      type        = "*"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject"
    ]

    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.arn}/*"]

  }

  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.arn}/*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.frontend_vote_cloudfront_oai.iam_arn]
    }
  }

}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "frontend_vote_cloudfront_oai" {
  comment    = "frontend_vote origin"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "frontend_vote-bucket-ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.id

  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerEnforced"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "frontend_vote-static" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.bucket

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote, aws_s3_object.index_file_vote]

}

resource "aws_s3_object" "index_file_vote" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.id
  key    = "index.html"
  source = "./vote/index.html"

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote]

}

resource "aws_s3_object" "myicon_vote" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.id
  key    = "myicon.png"
  source = "./vote/myicon.png"

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote]

}

resource "aws_s3_object" "stylecss_vote" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.id
  key    = "style.css"
  source = "./vote/style.css"

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote]
}
```

Then apigateway is created via tf, 2 routes, 2 integrations:

```
# ###########################################
# # api gateway
# ###########################################

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "main_apigateway" {
  name          = var.apigateway_name
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  cors_configuration {
    allow_credentials = false
    allow_headers     = ["accept", "content-type"]
    allow_methods = [
      "GET",
      "OPTIONS",
      "POST",
    ]
    allow_origins = [
      # "*",
      "https://${aws_cloudfront_distribution.cloudfront_result.domain_name}",
      "https://${aws_cloudfront_distribution.cloudfront_vote.domain_name}"
    ]
    expose_headers = []
    max_age        = 0
  }
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "default" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.id
  name        = "$default"
  auto_deploy = true
}

# ###########################################
# # VOTE lambda backend integration
# ###########################################

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "vote_integration" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.id
  # integration_uri  = aws_lambda_function.vote_lambda_backend.invoke_arn
  integration_uri        = aws_lambda_function.vote_lambda_backend.arn
  integration_type       = "AWS_PROXY"
  payload_format_version = "2.0"

}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "vote_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.id
  route_key = "POST /voting"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.vote_integration.id}"
}


# resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "vote_policy_basic_execution_attachment" {
#   role       = aws_iam_role.vote_lambda_iam_role.name
#   policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam:aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
# }


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "vote_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.vote_lambda_backend.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.execution_arn}/*/*/voting"
}

# ###########################################
# # RESULT lambda backend integration
# ###########################################

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "result_integration" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.id
  # integration_uri  = aws_lambda_function.result_lambda_backend.invoke_arn
  integration_uri        = aws_lambda_function.result_lambda_backend.arn
  integration_type       = "AWS_PROXY"
  payload_format_version = "2.0"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "result_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.id
  route_key = "GET /results"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.result_integration.id}"
}


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "result_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.result_lambda_backend.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.execution_arn}/*/*/results"
}
```

In that new API endpoint I want to put it in my `index.html`. How to replace old API with newly created one? Via bash?

Index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  < SOME CODE>
        

    <script>
    
      var backend_url = "https://5y7dfynd34.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/voting" #this backend is old 


       SOME OTHER CODE
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't think using environment variables like `aws_lambda` in terraform will work here.

Comment: Are S3 and API Gateway created in the same module?

Comment: no - its 2 diff files

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variable to template file.

Lets convert your `index.html` to `index.html.tpl` on `vote` directory.

index.html.tpl

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <SOME CODE>
        

    <script>
    
      var backend_url = ${backend_api_url}

       SOME OTHER CODE
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can pass variable to template file with `templatefile` function.
You just need to change from `source` to `content` in your resource.

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "index_file_vote" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.id
    key    = "index.html"
    content = templatefile("./vote/index.html.tpl", {
        backend_api_url = var.your_backend_api_url
    })
  
    depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote] 
}
```

Comment: thx u, but when i upload .tpl not .html file to s3 - will s3 recognize it as valid html file? since i have to rename the extension to tpl

Comment: `key` attribute is S3 file name. Only you will keep tpl on local and updated tpl will upload to S3 as `index.html` by terraform's `templatefile`